# JAVA regex for "String, String."

Tags: java, regex

Given string "Neil, Gogte., Satyam, B.: Introduction to Java"

I need to extract only "Neil, Gogte." and "Satyam, B." from given string using regex how can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You need to provide some code what you tried

Comment: If this is the case, I would choose `substring()` over regular expression.

Comment: Try splitting on `(?<=\.),`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matcher` to `group`

```
String str = "Neil, Gogte., Satyam, B.: Introduction to Java";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+, [a-zA-Z]+\\.)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while(matcher.find()){
    String result = matcher.group();
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to split the string. This matches any locations where `.,` exist:

```
(?<=\.),\s*
```

- `(?<=\.)` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is a literal dot character `.`
- `,\s*` Matches `,` followed by any number of whitespace characters

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##ZY5PS8NAEMXPzacYctqUuHcTS1EQUVCEHI2HMdnGjfuP2UmxSD973NjSi6cZ3u@9xxtxj1c@KDf2X9fzrG3wxDAmVU6sjVzX2T@N1KC@5SsyK3J1lnUGY4Rn1A5@slWYPozuIDJyOnuve7AJiYZJu@HtHZCGWCzO1U47NHACEGED@YvSpoQHP7CSJTTIB7Ql3MkKHh2T76eOtXfAHp7SnLy@lJzXAKWW8y87b4M2SuRie7NpW1mUbRvXebGkLmtIxclwSpGMwWgW8Y/fEuEhysik0IqTqZA7T/fYfYrmEFlZ6SeuqpCK2LgldcyO8/wL)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String s = "Neil, Gogte., Satyam, B.: Introduction to Java";
        final Pattern r = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\.),\\s*");
        String[] result = r.split(s);
        Arrays.stream(result).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Neil, Gogte.
Satyam, B.: Introduction to Java
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use this regex to match your names:

[`[A-Z][a-z]+, [A-Z][a-z]*\.`](https://regex101.com/r/qRMzeS/1)

In Java:

`[A-Z][a-z]+, [A-Z][a-z]*\\.`

That would match

- `[A-Z]` Match an uppercase character
- `[a-z]+` Match one or more lowercase characters
- `,` Match comma and a whitespace
- `[A-Z]` Match an uppercase character
- `[a-z]*` Match zero or more lowercase characters
- `\.` Match a dot

[Demo Java](http://rextester.com/FPMX19965)